# java mysterious classpath behavior

Tags: java, classpath

I failed specifying the class path. Here's my setup:

File: **"root/src/hello/German.java"**

```
   package hello;
   public class German {
        public void greet() { System.out.println("Hallo"); }
   }
```

I compile this in "root":

```
> javac root/src/hello/German.java -d root/package
```

where "root/package/hello" exists as an empty directory. Fine. Now I want to test and write

File: **"root/test/testHello.java"**

```
import hello.German;
public class helloTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        German guy = new German();
        guy.greet();
    }
}
```

I compile

```
> javac testHello.java -cp ../package
```

To summarize, I have:

1. **root/package/hello/German.class**
2. **root/test/helloTest.class**

I execute in "root/test/":

```
 > java testHello                      => class not found except.
 > java testHello -cp ../package       => class not found except.
 > java testHello -cp ../package/hello => class not found except.
```

However, copying the 'hello' directory into test such that there is

1. **root/test/hello/German.class**
2. **root/test/helloTest.class**

I **can** execute in "root/test/"

```
 > java testHello
```

and it greets friendly in German. I want to specify the classpath, though. But, I have no idea why '-cp' and '-classpath' is not accepted.

Comment: The classpath (_cp_) instructions must be placed before the main class name. `java -cp ../package testHello `, or they will be considered as parameters to your main class, not java options .

Comment: "java -cp ../package/ testHello" complains that it cannot load main class 'testHello'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -classpath .:../package testHello
```

`.:../package` to use the current directory and `../package` as classpath.